# QML Module not found with registered types

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I have the following Issue:

In `main.qml` I get these errors. Although I can use these types perfectly in the code. It looks like it is just an intellisense issue.

[image: f5bb7882-0104-47bb-be23-e2d160bc7c2c-image.png]

These types are registered in `main.cpp`:

[image: e745d480-b943-490b-9bba-f253dc8f4974-image.png]

Thse classes are defined in the `include` folder:

My folder structure looks like this:

[image: a4997bc8-5c83-459d-85e0-de8fb6eade18-image.png]

Do I have to modify `QML_IMPORT_PATH` in the pro file? I added src and include folder but it does not work:

```
QML_IMPORT_PATH += src
QML_IMPORT_PATH += include
```

The code itself runs fine. It is just an Intellisense issue.

Comment: I think you need to generate a plugins.qmltypes file: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-modules-with-plugins.html#generating-qmltypes-files

Comment: So I have to put this one in the root folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is simply a Qt Creator bug. Take a look at [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-23591) one. `qmlRegisterSingletonInstance` was added to the Qt library in version Qt 5.14. Even though Qt Creator 4.13.3 was built with Qt 5.15.2, the QML code model it uses has apparently still not been updated.

Comment: I think you are right. If I register one of the types with `qmlRegisterType` all the intellisense stuff works well. Really weired that they have not updated Creator for this (Maybe in Qt 6?).

Answer (score -1):

You need to run this code. QtCreator is notorious for flagging errors that don't exist or won't exist. It flags header files for .ui files because you haven't run a build yet so they haven't been generated. Many developers paint their UI files then do a fake build just to generate those files so QtCreator shuts up.

The other thing you need to do is provide the full source code for one of those classes. (I will assume they all have the same issue.)

The [example Qt gives here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonInstance) isn't a good one. You should never be able to "new" a Singleton. The constructor should be protected and the Instance() method should construct one and only one if the internal pointer is null.

Do you actually have a method named get() in each of those classes? Does it actually return a pointer? Many return a reference, that is why I'm asking. If we overlook the glaring error of being able to "new" a Singleton, there is one good thing in this example.

```
QScopedPointer<SingletonTypeExample> example(new SingletonTypeExample);
```

They used a QScopedPointer to the class.

```
qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("Qt.example.qobjectSingleton", 1, 0, "MyApi", example.get());
```

Once you actually build you will have all of the MOC information where it needs to be. This may well make QtCreator happy. Honestly, I've stopped looking at what QtCreator flags anymore because there are so many false alarms.

Comment: Code build and runs fine. It does not make QtCreator happy.

Comment: Then this answer is correct. QtCreator is notorious for flagging errors that don't exist. In your particular case the static source analyzer can't go rummaging through the code to find qmlRegisterSingletonInstance where it lists your class. The Build system is what exposes your class to QML. It isn't an integral part of QML so static code analysis can't find it.